# Is possible to keep rows matching a condition always on top in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL table as following image shows:
[image]

Now I want to select the data by keeping the `type`=2 always on the top, like this:
[image]

How can I implement this using one SQL statement?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id, 
       type, 
       name, 
       register 
FROM   table 
ORDER  BY CASE type
           WHEN 2 THEN 1000000 
           ELSE id 
          END CASE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, 
       TYPE, 
       name, 
       register 
FROM   table 
ORDER  BY field(TYPE,2) desc
```